# Грамотно ли я отвечаю на вопрос "Как дела?"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я отвечаю так: «Может быть». Для меня это — как синоним *нормально*, т. е. моя жизнь может быть принята... и т. д.

Скажите, это корректно? Грамотно как ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посчитал такой ответ несоответствующим вопросу - подумал бы, что меня не расслышали. Ваш ответ - допущение вероятности чего-то, в то время как вопрос «Как дела?» является попыткой получения оценки текущей ситуации, а не вероятности чего бы то ни было.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный вопрос-приветствие «Как дела?» не содержит и не подразумевает понятие *жизнь* (моя жизнь может быть принята). Существует представление о *деловой жизни*, но здесь и о ней речи нет, и стало быть, ответ не может существовать в контексте заданного вопроса.

Такому вашему ответу (и тоже с натяжкой) соответствовал бы вопрос, где бы было слово *жизнь*: «Как жизнь? Ответ: «Может быть». А вопросу «как дела?» — ответ: «Идут».

Answer (score 1):

Корректно то, что может быть правильно понято собеседником. А Ваш ответ непонятен тому, кто не знаком с необычным ходом Вашей мысли.